# Get sed to read from terminal

Tags: shell, unix, sed, terminal

I'm sorry if this seems like a silly question, but I'm a little new to this.
I need write a script to get a string from the terminal and use sed to print it back to the terminal, with one word on each line.
eg. 'This is input' should give me
This
is
input

I tried my hand at writing the script, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo -n 'Enter the text:' 
read text
sed -i "/$text/s/ /\n/g"
```

I've saved it in a file called 1.sed, and run it with the command ./1.sed
Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `sed` command to following:

```
echo 'this is input' | sed -r 's/(\w+)\s+/\1\n/g'
```

`(\w+)\s+` - capture a word which is followed by one or more space in `\1`

Answer (score 0):

Doing the same with `awk`

```
echo 'this is input' | awk 1 RS=" "
this
is
input
```

Another version

```
echo 'this is input' | awk 'gsub(/ /,"\n")'
```